# I want to use google play service v8.1.0 in my android app. What to do if user's device doesn't have google play service v8.1.0?

Tags: android

I am using android studio and already added

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

in dependencies.
I am using min sdk version 10 and normally api 10 is preloaded with play services v4.0.27.
so is there is any other way to use feature of play services v8.1.0 features without updating it in device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so is there is any other way to use feature of play services v8.1.0 features without updating it in device?

No.

Comment: There is no way to use play services v8.1.0 as a library in my project?

Comment: I am using play services v8.1.0 to gey user's location and getting a permission to turn on location service from alert dialog. So there is another way to accomplish this task?

Comment: @SaurabhBorse: The Play Services SDK is mostly just an API. That API talks to the Play Services Framework, which is an app on Android devices. You have stated that you do not want users to have to update this app. Hence, you cannot use an updated SDK either, as the SDK will demand that the Play Services Framework app be as new (or newer) than the SDK.

Comment: @SaurabhBorse: "So there is another way to accomplish this task?" -- no.